# Why telling me couldn't map stack to segment?

Tags: c, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm doing the attack lab of CS:APP. I typed "./ctarget -q" but it returned

> Cookie: 0x59b997fa
>
> Couldn't map stack to segment at 0x5558600

Look like something wrong with the stack, but I do not know how to fix it.

And actually it is fine with the "rtarget", which is really strange.

By the way, I'm doing this on wsl.

This is a problem on http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/labs.html. The self-study handout of Attack lab http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/target1.tar . And I don't have a source code.

Comment: You need to post your code and how you're trying to run it.

Comment: I think most people here including me will not know what "CS:APP" is.  Posting a link to the exact piece of code you are trying to run would really help anyone who wants to investigate this.  Even better would be if you could simplify the code, removing all the bits that aren't needed to reproduce this problem, and then post a [mcve] (so no reference to a book is needed).  I am guessing there is some obscure Linux system call that the WSL did not implement fully.  You could try running the real Linux kernel in VirtualBox or VMWare and see if things work.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, and I sloved it by updating wsl to wsl2.